# Get related objects from a queryset, preserving the ordering

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model, which looks something like this:

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['first_name', 'last_name', ]
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ... some other fields ...

class Point(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent)
    ... some other fields ...
```

When I select some points I want them to be ordered by agent names, like this:

```
points = Point.objects.filter(...smth...).order_by(-agent)
```

So the resulting queryset is ordered by agent names, from Z to A

or

```
points = Point.objects.filter(...smth...).order_by(agent)
```

or even without ordering

The question is:
How to get a queryset or a list of unique agent objects from `points` queryset, preserving the ordering?

Preferrably, without any more `order_by()` statements, because the view may or may not be explicitly aware of ordering type

Something like `set(points.values_list('agent', flat=True))`, but with objects instead of pk-s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own idea and nest it like so (where `points` is any `QuerySet` of `Point`):

```
Agent.objects.filter(id__in=points.values_list('agent', flat=True))
```

Django ORM will translate this into a single db query. This should have `Agent`'s default order. In order to preserve the agent order in points, you could do:

```
[p.agent for p in points.distinct('agent')]
```

This workaround, obviously, is not a queryset and `distinct` with field arguments is only supported in Postgres.

Comment: I have already tried this, and guess what? It appears that `values_list` does not preserve ordering! Also, `id__in` applies default ordering on resulting queryset

Comment: Also, I try to preserve agent ordering from `points` queryset, thus overriding `Agent`'s default ordering

Comment: I see, if you don't need a queryset: `[p.agent for p in points.distinct('agent')]` should preserve points order, does an extra loop however, also `distinct(*fields)` is only supported by Postgres

Comment: This seems like a working solution... for those who use Postgres (

Comment: could you post your proposal as an answer so I mark it as correct?

Comment: No problem, that's just another reason to migrate to Postgres =)

Answer (score 0):

Use Agent objects manager, and [`QuerySet.distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) to get unique agents:

```
Agent.objects.filter(point__condition=...).distinct().order_by('-pk')
```

NOTE: `condition=...` should be adjusted to `point__condition=...`.

Comment: could you please explain what does 'condition' stands for?

Comment: @MikeDoudkin, It depends. For examles, `....smth...` in the question was `last_name='John'`, it need to be converted to `point__last_name='John'`

Comment: As with the @Parag answer, it appears that my post was somewhat misleading - it made you think that I want agents to be reverse-ordered all the time, but the truth is that ordering is arbitrary. I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Agent.objects.filter(id__in=Point.objects.values_list('agent_id', flat=True)).order_by('-first_name')
```

**Update:**

```
Point.objects.filter(agent_id__in=Agent.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)).distinct('agent').order_by('-agent__first_name')
```

Comment: My post was somewhat misleading - it made you think that I want agents to be reverse-ordered all the time, but the truth is that ordering is arbitrary. I have edited my post

Comment: As with @schwobaseggl 's answer, this will work, but only on Postgres (I use MySQL)